# How to Refer to Enumerated Subsections and Subsubsections?

Tags: writing, writing-style

Body

```
There is Subsection 1.2.
There is Subsubsection 1.4.1.
```

Referring in the body now

```
See Subsection 1.2. 
See Subsubsection 1.4.1.
```

I would like to replace all `sub` parts simply by section etc the following but not sure if correct

```
See Section 1.2.
See Section 1.4.1.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should eliminate "sub" from the labels.  It is easier to understand and easier to update when the sections change.

Comment: Can you please give an example what you mean? Do you mean to refer Section 1.4.2 or Subsubsection 1 or just Section 1?

Comment: "See Section 3.1.4.1.5.9"